# How to change the default set/get of an object in Kotlin?

Tags: properties, kotlin, delegation

I'm looking for a way to override how the String getter function works, but I wasn't able to find any solution. Any way to do this?
I know delegated properties works, but I'm looking for a way to override the default setter and getter, without having to declare "`by SomeDelegate()`".

I tried something like

```
operator fun String?.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): String {
    return "it works"
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: You can't override default behavior with Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve. There is no "default set/get of an object"; a `String` _is_ a `String`, and operations that work with a `String` access it directly, without going through any intermediate methods.